# Installation on debian 5 32-bit without being a root

Tags: linux, software-installation, non-root-user

I am trying to install Skype and Google Chrome on my desktop. It runs Debian 5 32-bit. I downloaded the packages from the web but I have no idea how to install them.

Answer (score 3):

There are options for installing software without root access.
First of all, using the sources (if available) you can build and use most packages as a non-root user -- but this "from sources" way forces you to deal with *dependencies*, as well.
Starting from that, [pkgsrc](http://www.pkgsrc.org) makes this easier, by offering a large number of, say, recipes to build packages *and their dependencies* (so-called "ports").
[It supports non-root operation, see this FAQ entry.](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/pkgsrc/faq.html#non-root-pkgsrc)  There is a [guide on how to use pkgsrc here.](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/pkgsrc/)

Regarding the packages you're looking for, they have "ports" in pkgsrc: [`wip/chromium`](http://pkgsrc.se/wip/chromium), [`net/skype21`](http://pkgsrc.se/net/skype21).  (Where [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/), the Open Source project related to Google Chrome, is available as a work-in-progress package only, i.e. via [`wip.sf.net`](http://wip.sourceforge.net), a repository of additional ports to pkgsrc.

Also, there is [ZeroInstall](http://0install.net/), which as far as I know provides *binary packages* that you can install in some way not requiring root permissions. (Of course you need to install ZeroInstall first, which you can -- if your sysadmin doesn't install the `zeroinstall-injector` Debian package for you -- install from source, too, as [explained here](http://0install.net/install-source.html).)  I'm not sure if this way is less involved, though.  (From a quick look, they seem to have Chromium and Skype packages, but the first one looks kind of old.)

---

The bottom line: it is possible, but involves some work and things to learn (which can be considered a good thing, while time-consuming).  The easiest way probably is calling your sysadmin to install the Debian packages you want to use.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to install a package with a double click, first you should install an application that with handle that. In a terminal write

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

if you do not have a root password, or

```
su -c 'apt-get install gdebi'
```

if you have a root password.

After that the double click in the filemanager should work.

Google Chrome, in the unbranded version called Chromium is available in the package `chromium-browser`, so no need to download the package, simply run

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, when I typed the first instruction, the terminal complained because my username is not in the sudoers file. Is there anyway out of this?

Comment: @Angie: so you should use the second version, and provide the root password.

Comment: I do not have the root password (the systems guy at work refuses to give it to me). I guess I'll have to ask him to install my programs... Thanks for your response!

Comment: Yeah, if you're not the sysadmin then you're not going to be allowed to install software to the system. Software like `gdebi` -- or `sudo` for that matter -- is meant for the sysadmin to make his own job easier without having to su to root for everything, not to give random users admin privileges...