# Installing software as user

Tags: linux, non-root-user

I need to install some software as user on a machine where I don't have root access.

So far I've been using [gentoo-prefix](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/gentoo-alt/prefix/), but ain't really fine with it: I need GCC 4.6 and gentoo only ships 4.5, I don't like having to compile everything, and I'm not a fan of gentoo and portage.

Is there any other option of doing that?
Something like a fakeroot wouldn't be enough?

Comment: [Might be a duplicate](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29646/11539), anyway, I'd answer in quite [the same way](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29696/11539). (While `pkgsrc` doesn't save you from compiling yourself, `zeroinstall` probably could.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are downloading a source of the GCC you can simply compile it and have it installed in your home directory.

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/gcc-4.6
```

should do it.

Once you do that just make sure that `$HOME/gcc-4.6/bin` is in the path before `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` and `$HOME/gcc-4.6/lib` is added to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.