# Is there a drawback when using a chroot in high performance computing?

Tags: chroot, high-performance

My (small) company uses an out-of-date linux (centos) software stack to run a proprietary software on a small cluster. Understandingly, IT is reluctant to upgrade since everything works now.

I'd like to do some performance tests on these machines and plan to install a lot of software that shouldn't interfere with the production root. It also includes compiling scientific packages and therefor I need up-to-date libraries. One possiblity is to install an entire up-to-date root in a different location and `chroot` into it.

**My question is:** How will this impact the performance of the tools running inside the chroot? Are there any benchmark references available? Is this technique widespread/disadvantegous/dangerous? Other ideas? See also my [related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35523/what-is-an-effective-method-for-installing-up-to-date-software-on-an-out-dated-p).

Comment: Only root can use chroot. If you can become root, then this is a good approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A chroot should not impact performance. I haven't heard of any benchmark on it because it's really just a mapping between two spaces.

Anyway, for your problem, maybe it should be better to use something like [LXC](http://lxc.sourceforge.net/). Instead of moving somethings working, you can simply create a LXC and do your stuff inside this LXC. LXC is far better than chroot and has really less drawback.

You can see it like a chroot v2.0. As far as I know, it should works well on CentOS 5.X.

Comment: Has LXC no performance hit?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of chrooting, why don't you take advantage of [environment modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) (something you'll see on nearly every linux cluster these days), and install the software to an alternative location?