# netcdf installation and usr/local... folders

Tags: compiling, software-installation, opensuse, directory-structure

I need to install netcdf on a SuSE Linux machine but I am having a few problems understanding the usr/local/ folders and my the myusername/local/ folders. What I think I need to do is go into the uncompressed netcdf folder and do

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/netcdf-gfortran
```

However I need to create this folder, right? and why in usr/local and not in my username/local ...?

Comment: Why don't you just grab the official package from http://software.opensuse.org/package/netcdf ? What version of SUSE Linux are we talking about?

Comment: Hi, I am running. openSUSE 11.3 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11.3. with regards to the suse netcdf package I cannot do that as it's limited by my sys administrator and I will have to compile other things in the future so I may as well learn ho to do it properly once and for all...

Answer (score 1):

The usual combo is:

```
./configure --prefix=... [more options]
make
make install
```

You probably won't want to use `/usr/local` since that should require root permissions too, so it's `--prefix=$HOME` or `--prefix=$HOME/programs` (or whatever else works better for you).

It might be worthwhile to talk to your sysadmin regarding additional software - you should talk to him anyway, since openSUSE 11.3 is way past its end of life. At least he should upgrade to the [11.4 Evergreen](http://en.opensuse.org/Evergreen), which receives at least security updates.

As for building the packages, it is usually a good idea to have a look at the [.spec files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager#SPEC_file) to have some idea of what might be useful `configure` options, source code patches and building tricks - in your case you'd probably want to check [netcdf .spec file for openSUSE:Factory](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/openSUSE%3aFactory/netcdf/netcdf.spec?expand=1) (or any older distribution).

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, under Linux, `/usr` is for programs provided by the distribution and managed by its package manager (dpkg/apt, rpm/yum, emerge, etc.) and `/usr/local` is for programs installed and managed manually by the system administrator. Programs under `/usr` and `/usr/local` are installed for all users.

If you want to install programs for your own use, put them somewhere under your home directory.

I recommend using [Stow](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) or [XStow](http://xstow.sourceforge.net/) to keep track of the programs that you install manually. (Use one or the other: they are implementations of the same concept.) When you install programs manually, you have a choice between two inconvenient options:

- Put all programs in the same directory. Then you'll have a hard time sorting them out, figuring which files belong to which programs, uninstalling programs, etc. On the flip side, all programs are easy to use: you only need to update your PATH and other similar settings once.
- Put each program in its own directory. Then uninstallation is as easy as `rm -r`. The downside is that you have to add each program to PATH and so on.

Stow gives you the best of both worlds. This tool maintains symbolic links from a common directory to a per-program directory. You install each program (from source or from a binary package) in its own directory under `stow`, and Stow creates symbolic links in `bin`, `lib`, `man`, …

So create a directory `programs/stow` under your home directory. Install netcdf with

```
./configure --prefix=~/programs/stow/netcdf-gfortran-4.3
make
make install
```

Then run `stow netcdf-gfortran-4.3` from the `~/programs/stow` directory to create symbolic links for all the parts of that package.

Edit your `.profile` (or wherever you put your environment settings) to add `~/programs/bin` to your executable search path, `~/programs/lib` to your library search path, etc.

```
PATH="$HOME/programs/bin:$PATH"
if [ -n "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" ]; then
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/programs/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
else
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/programs/lib"
fi
if [ -z "$MANPATH" ]; then
  MANPATH=$(manpath)
fi
export MANPATH="$HOME/programs/share/man:$HOME/programs/man:$MANPATH"
```

When compiling programs, pass `--with-cppflags="-I $HOME/programs/include"` to `configure` so that it can find headers in the stow area.

For more information, see [Keeping track of programs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16375/keeping-track-of-programs/16397#16397) and [What is an effective method for installing up-to-date software on an out-dated production machine?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35523/what-is-an-effective-method-for-installing-up-to-date-software-on-an-out-dated-p/35587#35587)