# Compile a program without sudo access

Tags: compiling, software-installation, non-root-user

I am connected to a linux system with SSH in my college. I found that [ctorrent](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ctorrent/?source=directory) is a console alternative of bitorrent. I have downloaded the tar.gz source but to compile/install it needs sudo access

Is there a way to install the program without sudo access?

I don't know a lot about linux and cannot make [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42569/29231) work with ctorrent.

Comment: please specify error you got,when following the above method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can install it locally in your home directory. Ususally it can be done by specifying the parameter **prefix** for **configure** script.
For example,

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME
```

So, when you compile sources configured in such way, then you will call

```
make install
```

the binaries will install into you **$HOME/bin**
Also, you should alternate PATH variable.
You can do this in $HOME/.bashrc  in next way

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Anyway, if your sources don't have usual build system - you can just compile it, manually put in $HOME/bin and alternate PATH variable (to make it available without specifying the full path to binary).

Comment: I was getting permission errors on configure. I changed the permission and allowed execution which compiled it successfully