# How to customize Linux without sudo/root access?

Tags: linux, software-installation, non-root-user, suse

In my company I do not have sudo or root access to the Linux server but I still want to install my softwares and customize it to my taste.

What is a good practice to install applications to your 'user' directory that won't require root/sudo access. I've ran into multiple problems when trying to do this, that's why I don't want to focus this question to one particular application, but a general thumb rule on how to go about this process so that you don't create more problems than you solve.

Linux Info:

```
cat /etc/*-release
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 (x86_64)
VERSION = 10
PATCHLEVEL = 3
LSB_VERSION="core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-noarch:core-2.0-x86_64:core-3.0-x86_64"
```

Comment: For how to install, see [How to install program locally without sudo privileges?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42567/how-to-install-program-locally-without-sudo-privileges) and [Keeping track of programs](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16375/keeping-track-of-programs). For how to configure, that tends to come naturally: use the application's setup interface or edit the configuration files in your home directory.

Comment: That being said, the easiest way to install an application is with your package manager, as root. Install applications manually only when they aren't available from your package manager.