# Right way of creating a local filesystem hierarchy within /home

Tags: software-installation, directory-structure, non-root-user, home

I am an user with **no superuser rights**. I normally build and install the tools I need within my **`/home/<user>`** directory, and then create aliases to be able to run my programs. However, this is creating a bit of a mess.

What would be a saner way of creating a filesystem hierarchy within **`/home/<user>`** so that I can have something resembling better a *Linux Filesystem Hierarchy*? Something similar to a Python virtualenv, so I can install libraries I need without needing superuser support?

Comment: I recommend [GNU stow](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) (which I wrote about in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16375/keeping-track-of-programs; >>TODO update that and mention stow on http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42567/how-to-install-program-locally-without-sudo-privileges).

Comment: @Gilles, sounds like THE answer! Post an answer and I'll choose it once I can verify it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use - *if you can get the initial right to do so granted to you* - the linux kernel's *User* namespaces. In a user namespace a user can be apportioned a piece of a disk and run a full-fledged container within as a super-user without otherwise affecting the parent environment. You will need a 3.8 or later kernel, some linux-savvy, and the initial setup before it will work.

Comment: I didn't know that. It won't work in my current situation, unfortunately. We're running **very** stable. ;7)

Comment: @dmvianna - that's a shame. That said, 3.8 is only the point at which the namespaces as a whole were considered complete - the user namespace was the last. The mount namespaces, on the other hand, were introduced in 2.5 or 2.6. A mount namespace allows a process to have its own private mount tree. Given your own shell with its own private mount tree, you could privately mount home with other rights than other processes have - and do a permanent `chroot` like scenario in that way. And never underestimate the power of `mount --bind` given a little ingenuity and a lot of `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: This is a good idea. However, I do not want to shadow the current root system, just overlay on it. Mounting over `/usr/local` would be nice, for example, except that **I don't have mounting rights**. Same obviously goes to `chroot`. :P

Comment: @dmvianna - yes - that is a hangup. You can overlay it with shared mounts - that is a deeply complex and powerful tool at a *super-user's* disposal. Anything useful you do along these lines - as I noted in the answer - is going to require initial setup and permission of a superuse.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make it clear in my question, but I would be happy to just have my personal `/home/<user>/usr/local`, etc., and it working seamlessly for me. I am able to do just that, except that the hierarchy looks more like an `/opt` (it follows the program, not the Unix standard), and interoperability between programs fails. That is, I can only have programs that do not rely on shared libraries. Are you telling me it cannot be done or are you telling me you don't know how to do just that?

Comment: @dmvianna - Well, I suppose it might be done if you simply compiled everything yourself with the right path prefixes - but precompiled binaries will almost always point to the defaults. The only to way to handle that is a symlink or a mount. You cannot - and shouldn't want to - install symlinks into `{/usr,}/bin:/lib` without root priveleges, but you might shadow a mount tree with a somewhat peculiar `/etc/fstab` as a non-root user.

Comment: Yep, I do compile everything and add prefixes. That's what gives me the `/opt` like hierarchy (which works to a point, but is not perfect). I might try the `/etc/fstab` route. However, it doesn't strike me as the cleanest thing, and will involve much institutional pain. :P

Comment: @dmvianna - agreed - it is not ideal. A container would be ideal. There are other - less simply implemented - containerization options available to you. The user namespace was my first suggestion because it is a builtin feature to the linux kernel - though that may have its own problems as some distros do not enable that compile-time option. Given that kernel feature it is probably the most simple way to go, next best - as far as I know - is custom shared mount tree. But, as I said, painful or not, anything useful along these lines will require initial institutional support. Sorry.

Comment: This looks like the answer to me: [shared subtrees](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt)

Comment: @dmvianna - yup, that's the one - and precisely the doc I had in mind when I was referring to *next best*. It can, unfortunately though, get *very complicated*. Most important, as I've found, you must `mount --make-rundbindable` the root of the share when you share it. Otherwise you wind up *recursively* mounting it over itself when you do - it can get pretty messy that way. Like, mounting `/` in `/tmp/root` will get `/tmp/root/tmp/root/tmp/root`.... and so on. If `/tmp/root` is unbindable though, it cuts that problem off at the head.