# What is the per-user correlate of /usr/share?

Tags: directory-structure, non-root-user, geany

At a low level, `/usr/share/geany.glade` does configure some important aspects of Geany which are not controlled by `geany.conf` (e.g., visibility of the `menubar`). Copying a modified `geany.glade` file in `~/.local/share/geany/` did not make any change. So, how can this program be altered without root privileges?, what is the local directory where this file is to be placed, such that it overrides the content of `/usr/share/geany.glade`, much in the same way as `.conf` files can be stored in `.config/share`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`geany.glade` defines the user interface, and isn’t user-overridable (in the same way that the application’s code isn’t user-overridable).

If you want to tweak the interface without being root, you’ll need to install your own copy of Geany in your home directory and modify it there.

Comment: Since the question was posted in a general way, I assume this will be the case for any other application.

Comment: How to install locallly: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42569/91304

Comment: Yes, the default case for files in `/usr/share` is that they’re not overrideable in a fashion similar to configuration files. Many programs do support additional files in user folders though (Emacs, Perl, Python, TeX...).