# How to print only 1 filename together with the matching pattern?

Tags: text-processing, performance, gnu-parallel

I want to print the filename/s together with the matching pattern but only once even if the pattern match has multiple occurrence in the file.

E.g. I have a list of patterns; `list_of_patterns.txt` and the directory I need to find the files is `/path/to/files/*`.

**list_of_patterns.txt**:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

**/path/to/files/**

```
/file1
/file2
/file3
```

Let say `/file1` has the pattern `A` multiple times like this:

**/file1**:

```
A
4234234
A
435435435
353535
A
```

(Also same goes to other files where there are multiple pattern match.)

I have this grep command running but it prints the filename every time a pattern matches.

`grep -Hof list_of_patterns.txt /path/to/files/*`

output:

```
/file1:A
/file1:A
/file1:A
/file2:B
/file2:B
/file3:C
/file3:B
... and so on.
```

I know sort can do this when you pipe it after the grep command `grep -Hof list_of_patterns.txt /path/to/files/* | sort -u` but it only executes when grep is finished. In the real world, my `list_of_patterns.txt` has hundreds of patterns inside. It takes sometimes an hour to finish the task.

Is there a better way to speedup the process?

**UPDATE:** some files have more than a hundred occurrences of matching pattern. E.g. `/file4` has occurrences of pattern `A` 900 times. That's why it's taking `grep` an hour to finish because it prints every occurrences of the pattern match together with the filename.

E.g. output:

```
/file4:A
/file4:A
/file4:A
/file4:A
/file4:A
/file4:A
/file4:A
/file4:A
... and so on til' it reach 900 occurrences.
```

I only want it to print only once.

E.g. Desired output:

```
/file4:A
/file1:A
/file2:B
/file3:A
/file4:B
```

Comment: Hundreds of patterns would not make `grep` take an hour to process a few files. Are your files also _very_ big or do you have many thousands of files to search in?

Comment: I think the option you are looking for is `-m1`

Comment: @Kusalananda, Yeah I think the files are causing this issue. I just found a file that has 1 pattern match only but with 950+ occurrences. That's why it takes an hour to finish.

Comment: @Sundeep Would that not discard the matches for some patterns? Only the first matching pattern in the pattern file would be reported.

Comment: @Sundeep, I'm using that now but still so slow. The problem is some files sometimes have 100+ occurrence of pattern match.

Comment: @Kusalananda `-m1` will cause exactly one output line per file, along with whatever pattern matched... not sure if OP wants one line for each matching pattern

Comment: @WashichawbachaW when you use `-m1`, grep will quit immediately after finding a matching line...

Comment: @Sundeep It would also not give matches for any but the first pattern that matches in the pattern file, so possible matches of later patterns would be missed for a particular file.

Comment: I have updated my question for clarification.

Comment: @WashichawbachaW, so you want to search each file against ALL patterns but display ALL matches in distinct (non-repeated) manner, right?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, yeah. Just exactly like `sort -u` does. Like I said in my question but it waits for grep to finish. Is there a way grep could perform what sort can do? Or there are other command that can perform the task better and faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a better way to speedup the process?

Yes, it's called GNU **`parallel`**:

```
parallel -j0 -k "grep -Hof list_of_patterns.txt {} | sort -u" ::: /path/to/files/*
```

- `j N` - number of jobslots. Run up to `N` jobs in parallel. `0` means as many as possible.
- `k` (`--keep-order`) - keep sequence of output same as the order of input
- `::: arguments` - use `arguments` from the command line as input source instead of stdin (standard input)

Comment: The `-j N` number should _possibly_ be limited to a number not too much higher than the available number of cores on the machine, especially if each individual `grep` against a file is slow.

Comment: What is the correct N for `-j N`? It depends: https://oletange.wordpress.com/2015/07/04/parallel-disk-io-is-it-faster/

Comment: If mixing results is acceptable, remove `-k` + use `--line-buffer` and instead of `sort -u`: `perl -ne '$s{$_}++ or print'`. This will give results before the full job is finished.

Comment: Can I install it without sudo permission?

Comment: @WashichawbachaW, if you are ready for some manual "experiments" - you may try https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42567/how-to-install-program-locally-without-sudo-privileges

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, I just installed it. I'm now running the command you provided. It's not done yet. So far it's not printing any duplicates like my previous output.

Comment: @WashichawbachaW, you are contradicting your conditions: 1) your phrase *yeah. Just exactly like sort -u does* ; 2) now you're saying *it's not printing any duplicates*. That's contradiction

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, what I mean about duplicates is the duplicate combination of `filename:pattern`. Just like `sort -u` does when it removes the duplicate `filename:pattern` combination. E.g. When in my old output I have 1 or more printed `/file1:A` now it only shows 1.

Comment: It's done. It took 49mins compared to 1hr 25mins from `grep`. Thanks @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: @WashichawbachaW, *it only shows 1* -  of course, that's what `sort -u` does (as you required earlier)