# How to install locally all sudo packages in my home directory?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, dpkg

I am blind to Linux, and I'm sorry if my question is too silly.
So I have access to a Linux server but cannot install any `sudo` packages as I have no administration right. Thus, I thought I could install `sudo dpkg` locally and install whatever package I need afterwards. I have seen a few discussions here but could not get the flow. Would be great if someone put some command line code here so that I and others could use it.
Thank you for your help!
Best,
ADR

Comment: If you could install your own `sudo` and gain rights that way, system security would be completely useless.

Comment: If you really can't live without the software in question *and* the actual sysadmin is unreasonable and won't install them for you, you may want to check if there's a flatpak or snap instead, which can be installed in userspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it the way you describe.

See this thread for learn more: [How to install program locally without sudo privileges?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42567/how-to-install-program-locally-without-sudo-privileges)

Comment: thanks! I have seen that thread, but quite difficult to follow as different issues were discussed as well.  Thanks !!